# Bootstrap botton hover

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bom eu tentei bastante mais não consegui fazer esses botões funcionarem como um hover no caso um onmousemove a intenção é essa invés de clicar apenas passar o mouser e aparecer o texto eu tentei acionar

> data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-2

no html pelo js com uma função de entrada mais não deu certo não é como um add.class bem estou sem idéias qualquer ajuda é valida des de já valew<3

```html
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link active" id="1" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-1"
                    aria-controls="pills-1" aria-selected="true">1</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link" id="2" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-2"
                    aria-controls="pills-2">2</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link" id="3" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-3"
                    aria-controls="pills-3" >3</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-1" >111111</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-2">222222</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-3">333333</div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria isto? No hover o texto aparece, faz exatamente o mesmo que o click mas em hover.

```js
$('.nav-link').on('mouseover', function(){
  //botões
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //texto
  var tabId = $(this).data('bs-target');
  $(tabId).addClass('active');
  $(tabId).addClass('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link active" id="1" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-1"
                    aria-controls="pills-1" aria-selected="true">1</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link" id="2" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-2"
                    aria-controls="pills-2">2</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="nav-link" id="3" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-3"
                    aria-controls="pills-3" >3</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-1" >111111</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-2">222222</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-3">333333</div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: exatamente isso <3 muito obrigado